# Table with horizontal scroll with sticky left column and sticky header on top of screen

Tags: html, css

I want to create a table with a horizontal scroll and a sticky left column and a sticky header on top of the screen. The table is wide, so I want to scroll it horizontally, but I need to make the first left column sticky. I also need to make the first row (header) sticky on top of the screen when the page is scrolled down. I don't know if these two options are compatible together. I've tried almost everything. Here is my latest code, which almost works, but the first row is not scrolling with the rest of the table. It could be made of divs or table elements, it doesn't matter.

I want to avoid using JavaScript.

```css
body {
  background: #F5F7FA;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10em auto 30em;
  max-width: 960px;
  overscroll-behavior: contain;
}

.headers {
  top: 0;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tracks,
.scroller {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.scroller {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.tracks {
  overflow: auto;
  scroll-snap-type: x mandatory;
}

.scenes::-webkit-scrollbar,
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.track {
  flex: 1 0 calc(22% + 2px);
  scroll-snap-align: start;
}

.track.first {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.track + .track {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.heading {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #efefef;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.entry {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  height: 8em;
  padding: 1em;
}


@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .track {
    flex: 1 0 calc(50% + 7px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="headers">
    
    <div class="scroller">
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="tracks">

    <div class="track first">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Option 1: Header scrolls with the rest of the table.
Option 2: Completely different solution with the same result.

Comment: So, with your code, the left column behave as you want, right ?

Comment: Yes, everything works well except for the header, which is not scrolling with rest of the table. I know why. It is not in the same div, but when I added it to the same div, it is not sticking to the top of the screen or the left column is not sticking to the left.

Comment: So the goal with this header is to fix it on top of page, right ? Can you edit your code to put it in a snippet so that we can see the render ?

Comment: Here you go. I didn't know about snippets, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

This is what it should look like, but without using JavaScript only with pure CSS.

```js
function scrollSynchronization() {
  const wrapper1 = document.querySelector('.scroller');
  const wrapper2 = document.querySelector('.tracks');

  wrapper1.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    wrapper2.scrollLeft = wrapper1.scrollLeft;
  });

  wrapper2.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    wrapper1.scrollLeft = wrapper2.scrollLeft;
  });
}

scrollSynchronization();
```

```css
body {
  background: #F5F7FA;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 10em auto 30em;
  max-width: 960px;
}

.headers {
  top: 0;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tracks,
.scroller {
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scroller {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.tracks {
  overflow: auto;
}

.scenes::-webkit-scrollbar,
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.track {
  flex: 1 0 calc(22% + 2px);
}

.track.first {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.track + .track {
  margin-left: -1px;
}

.heading {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  border: solid #fff;
  border-width: 0 1px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #efefef;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.entry {
  border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  border-top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  height: 8em;
  padding: 1em;
}


@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .track {
    flex: 1 0 calc(50% + 7px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="headers">

    <div class="scroller">
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 4</div>
      </div>
      <div class="track">
        <div class="heading">Heading 5</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="tracks">

    <div class="track first">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="track">
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="entry">
        <h3>Lorem, ipsum.</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does the snippet work without JavaScript? You mentioned in your anwser that this is pure CSS without JavaScript, but you have JavaScript there.

Comment: No, this is with JavaScript. I want this only with pure CSS. It does not work without JS.

Comment: So if I understand this right: this anwser isn't an actual anwser? It's just an example of the application how it should look like, but with JS?

Comment: Exactly. The result should look like this, but without using JS.